# Join EC2 instance to my Local Area Network

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Is it possible to join my EC2 instance (running Windows Server 2012 R2) to my LAN?

I don't want to make it a domain controller, but I want to have it local enough that I can ping other devices in local network from the AWS instance.

I read about using VPS but I think I may have misinterpreted it, isn't that more for connecting FROM your personal computer TO AWS for more secure browsing, etc?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you are looking for a Virtual Private Network (VPN).

You can configure this to put your EC2 instance on the same logical network as your home network and traffic between them goes over a secure private connection.

Amazon provide VPN access with their [Virtual Private Cloud](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/) (VPC) but there are also a number of open source implementations of VPNs you can try.

Answer (score 2):

AWS allow you to create your own private network 'in the cloud'. They call this VPC and it's fairly east to setup.

You can connect to your VPC in a number of ways, two examples:

## VPN

You can connect to instances in your VPC via VPN (over an Internet Connection).

## Direct Connect

You could also use Direct Connect to connect to instances in your VPC via a private network (ie NOT over the Internet).

- Faster
- Better ping/response times (more reliable)
- More secure (as it bypasses any and all Internet traffic)
- More costly (there are setup/ongoing charges with Direct Connect)

## More Info

### VPC & Peering

http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/

Also have a look at peering for communication between VPCs.

> Connect privately to other VPCs- Peer VPCs together to share resources
>   across multiple virtual networks owned by your or other AWS accounts.

### Direct Connect

http://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/

### Direct Connect & VPN

Setting Up AWS Direct Connect with VPN http://docs.aws.amazon.com/govcloud-us/latest/UserGuide/setting-up-direct-connect-with-vpn.html